# how to use valueforkey as if statement parameter

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I'm currently parsing a bunch of xml that looks roughly like this

```
<Rows>
<Row ID="76" MANUFACTURER="DIB" ISTENT="F"/>
<Row ID="38" MANUFACTURER="HIB" ISTENT="T"/>
<Rows>
```

I am wondering how I could use ISTENT in an if statement to only get back those values that are true.. or because these values are still strings and not boolean values = @"T" or something along those lines..

this is kinda what I have so far... but its no where near right.. Im hoping it'll give you an idea of what I am  trying.

```
if ([arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"] == @"T") {

    then pass my values over to custom method here.

}
```

But its not passing anything back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not be comparing strings with `==`. Use `isEqualToString:` method instead.

Second, I will assume you have already successfully parsed your XML data and you have an array of dictionaries containing the attributes of each row.

Third, you are not comparing strings since `[arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"]` will return an array containing the values of the `ISTENT` keys, which obviously you can not compare to an string directly.

Then, you could filter the original array like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISTENT",@"T"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [arrayData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The resulting array will only contain the rows where `ISTENT` is equal to `T`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: perfect.. thats exactly what I want.. 
Thank you very much for your explanations on what I was doing wrong.. I'm going to have a crack at this now.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. You have to use this method for comparing strings in objective-c:

```
if ([[arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
 //code here
}
```

According to [Apples class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) on NSString:

> - (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string is equal
> to the receiver using an literal Unicode-based comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using == on NSStrings will only compare the memory address, not the characters in the string. Use isEqualToString to compare NSStrings

```
[[arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"] isEqualToString:@"T"];
```

Note that is solution is case sensitive.

As for the boolean value, it depends on if your XML parser is smart enough to marshall the data correctly. What XML parser are you using?

Comment: cool, seems as though I'm doing something wrong as Im getting a sigabrt error... so just working thought that.. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @C.Johns Have a look at my answer. You can not use `[[arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"] isEqualToString:@"T"]` because `[arrayData valueForKey:@"ISTENT"]` is returning an array, which you can not compare to a string directly.